# Efficiently compute product of all other elements in Numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix, numeric

Let `A` be a 2D matrix. How can I compute a matrix `B`, such that each element of `B` is the *product of all other entries in the same row of* `A`?

Example:

```py
A = np.array([[5, 0, 6],   # the input
              [3, 1, 9],
              [2, 0, 0]])

B = np.array([[0, 30, 0],  # the result
              [9, 27, 3],
              [0,  0, 0]])
```

The naïve strategy (`B = np.prod(A, axis=-1, keepdims=True) / A`) runs into division-by-zero errors, and unfortunately these zeros are important elsewhere in the program and cannot trivially be replaced with tiny epsilons.

I've tried using `np.where` to address the three cases (rows without zeros, rows with one zero, rows with multiple zeros), but although that prevents NaNs in the output, it still requires computing everything up front before letting `np.where` pick and choose element-wise, which seems like a lot of code and unnecessary computational effort (and still produces div-by-zero warnings in the process).

What is the smartest, fastest way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213214/return-array-with-products-of-old-array-except-i/213254#213254) and, inspired by it, came up with the following efficient-ish solution:

```py
def products_of_others(a, axes=None):
    if axes is None:
        axes = tuple(range(a.ndim))
    if isinstance(axes, int):
        axes = (axes,)

    # flatten the desired axes into one last dimension
    original_shape = a.shape
    other_axes = tuple([ax for ax in range(a.ndim) if ax not in axes])
    new_ax_order = other_axes + axes
    old_ax_order = np.argsort(new_ax_order)
    a = np.transpose(a, new_ax_order)
    a = np.reshape(a, [original_shape[ax] for ax in other_axes] + [np.prod([original_shape[ax] for ax in axes])])

    after = np.concatenate([a[..., 1:], np.ones_like(a[..., 0:1])], axis=-1)
    before = np.concatenate([np.ones_like(a[..., 0:1]), a[..., :-1]], axis=-1)
    after_prod = np.cumprod(after[..., ::-1], axis=-1)[..., ::-1]
    before_prod = np.cumprod(before, axis=-1)

    # undo the flattening
    out = np.reshape(after_prod * before_prod, [original_shape[ax] for ax in other_axes] + [original_shape[ax] for ax in axes])
    out = np.transpose(out, old_ax_order)

    return out
```